# How to create .rdp file on Mac OS that allows auto-login

Tags: macos, remote-desktop, rdp

I'm working on a tool that generates .rdp files and then invokes them using Microsoft RDP Client. This tool is running on Mac OS.

Everything works well, the only problem is that I can't figure out of how I can generate 'password 51:b' field properly. On Windows this can be done easily by using CryptProtectData method from Crypt32.dll library. How can I do the same on Mac.

Another option could be to use "rdp://" URL scheme, but it doesn't seem allow to pass password this way.

So the question is how can I implement auto-login on Mac if I use third-party RDP client.

Comment: were you able to do it? I am also stuck in something like that.

Comment: @user5821368 I wasn't able to generate proper .rdp file. we ended up integrating XQuartz (FreeRdp) tool.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know you can't. You can however create a "User Account" and a Server configuration and add both to the client. The connection will then be visible on the main window and you just need to double click it.

To do so, you need to add the password to the Keychain, use `/usr/bin/security` to do so from a script. It needs to be a `generic-password` and saved in `com.microsoft.rdc.macos`. Also be sure to generate an ID according to the RDP Clients scheme, like `BFF77777-7777-7777-7777-777777777777`.

You may also set the permissions to read that key using `/usr/bin/security` and `set-generic-password-partition-list` specifying the right teamid (UBF8T346G9) and again `com.microsoft.rdc.macos`. You need the admin password to do this step.

Then you can alter the RDP Clients config file, which is a .sqlite file located at `/Users/$(whoami)/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.rdc.macos/Data/Library/Application Support/com.microsoft.rdc.macos/com.microsoft.rdc.application-data.sqlite`. Add the user configuration in the `ZCREDENTIALENTITY` table and make sure the `ZID` matches the one added to the keychain.

To add a server configuration you need to alter the `ZBOOKMARKENTITY` table. Just add a configuration by hand using the UI and look at the table to get a feeling of how it needs to be setup. Basically you link your user configuration with the server configuratio by making sure that `ZCREDENTIAL` in `ZBOOKMARKENTITY` matches `Z_PK` in `ZCREDENTIALENTITY` of your user configuration.

I know the answer is a bit late, but it may give you a starting point. This will however not fully automate the process, you will still need to go to the UI and double click the connection you want to use.